# How can we maintain a error Log file (.txt) on a device for a phonegap based iOS and android application ?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, logging

How can we maintain a error Log file (.txt) on a device for a phonegap based iOS and android application ? Just like we have error log file in native android applications. Is there any phone gap plugin available to maintain such logs in device only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin (Android only) [cordova-plugin-logtofile](https://github.com/andischerer/cordova-plugin-logtofile) which seems to do what you need.

It can be also manually achieved by using core plugin cordova-plugin-file: [Cordova Example: Writing to a file](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file).

Comment: Is there any solution for iOS?

Comment: I tried log-to-file but When I tried with cordova install I'm getting compilation issues and when I tried with npm install I'm getting class not found in 

window.logToFile.setLogfilePath(logPath, function () {
console.log("Logger Logpath set Successfully")
}, function (err) {
console.log("Logger Logpath not set", err)
});