# How to Read/Write from text file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, input

I asked this question before but didn't get an answer.
I'm developing a Cordova game and need to implement a save/load function. E.g A Save/Load progress, done locally. Preferable similar to the fstream used in C++ reading/writing into a local text file. I need this function to work even offline. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to read and write from text file in an HTML5 Javascript Canvas Phonegap game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774103/how-to-read-and-write-from-text-file-in-an-html5-javascript-canvas-phonegap-game) / _“I asked this question before but didn't get an answer.”_ – that was only five hours ago – show some patience, please, and don’t double-post.

Comment: Not 100% but you can't actually write files through js on filesystem

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Comment: Pardon me, I'm new and don't know how to quite bump my posts. Yes, it's been over 5 hours of searching for resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't interact with the local filesystem in Javascript, since it's client side. If you want to store a value from session to session in Javascript, then you should have a look at some other kind of storage :)
Have a look at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html - It should get you on the right track :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried the examples before and they don't work and I don't quite understand it. It's like reading chinese ):